# can not execute mysqli_num_rows

Tags: php, mysqli

i have a php file that insert animal name and check wether the animal is in the database or not. However i can not output the messege when the data is already exist. It always output the msg "value is inserted" and this msg

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test-insert.php on line 12

```
<?php
$host='localhost';
$user='root';
$password='root';
$dbname='pet';
$connect=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname) or die("can not connect to server");
if(@$_GET['submit']=='yes' && $_POST['animal']!="")
{
    $animal=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,trim($_POST['animal']));
    $query="INSERT INTO animal (animal) VALUES ('$animal')";
    $result=mysqli_query($connect,$query) or die("can not execute query".mysqli_error($connect));
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result))
    {
        echo "value is already exist !";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "value is inserted ";
        echo "<p>$query</p>";
    }
}
else // 1st form display
{
    echo "<form action='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?submit=yes' method='POST'>
            <input type='text' name='animal'>
            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='insert name'>";

}
?>
```

Comment: You need to create another query with SELECT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REPLACE your query variable to `SELECT` **INSTEAD** of `INSERT`

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM animal"
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query) or die("can not execute query".mysqli_error($connect));
if(mysqli_num_rows($result))
{
    echo "value is already exist !";
}
```

Comment: You might want to do `if(mysqli_num_rows($result)) > 0` instead :)

Comment: An "explanation" as to what you did, would be a nice touch ;-) I'm just surprised this got 3 upvotes without an explanation to start with.

Comment: It is weird that this got *any* upvotes... It does not provide a full solution.

Comment: Same thing seems to go with the other one (answer) @Vatev

Comment: Well.. that one has a chance of working I guess... Also user2955245 seems to be new - its not so bad for a first answer.

Comment: We'll give him another 20 rep points, then we'll pick on him/her lol - I'm kidding of course.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$host='localhost';
$user='root';
$password='root';
$dbname='pet';
$connect=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname) or die("can not connect to server");
if(@$_GET['submit']=='yes' && $_POST['animal']!="")
{
    $animal=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,trim($_POST['animal']));
    $checkquery="SELECT * FROM animal WHERE animal='".$animal."'";
    $checkresult=mysqli_query($connect,$checkquery) or die("can not execute query".mysqli_error($connect));
    if(mysqli_num_rows($checkresult))
    {
        echo "value is already exist !";
    }
    else
    {
        $query="INSERT INTO animal (animal) VALUES ('$animal')";
        $result=mysqli_query($connect,$query) or die("can not execute query".mysqli_error($connect));
        echo "value is inserted ";
        echo "<p>$query</p>";
    }
}
else // 1st form display
{
   echo "<form action='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?submit=yes' method='POST'>
        <input type='text' name='animal'>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='insert name'>";

}
?>
```

Comment: And could you describe what "YOU" did also? What's up with the answers today, feeding the vampires again.